# references to FAQ

Tags: bug, status-declined, badges

Now that the FAQ seems to have been transformed into 'help' there are a few problems with the `analytical` badge description.

That description both refers to 'FAQ' which should now be 'Help` or 'Help centre' <del>and the hyper link behind [FAQ](https://unix.stackexchange.com/faq) is no longer a valid link in the system and should be changed to https://unix.stackexchange.com/helpcenter</del>That hyper link now redirects to the new help centre.

Answer (score 1):

Analytical is actually impossible now, you can't earn it anymore. It's a known problem, but they haven't gotten around to fixing it; they're either going to come up with a new way to earn it or just replace it

Comment: Laura♦: [_The Analytical badge will no longer be awarded._](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/183128/analytical-badge-still-showing-faq)

Answer (score 0):

> The Analytical badge will no longer be awarded. It doesn't make sense to change it to "visited every page of the help center" because there's so much more content than in the old FAQ. Furthermore, this new help center is meant to be more reference material than single-sitting reading.
>
> This is just like the "beta" and "precognitive" badges on Stack Overflow; you simply can't earn them anymore.

--[Analytical Badge still showing "FAQ"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/183128/analytical-badge-still-showing-faq)